# prepend inside prepended element

Tags: jquery

I am having problems with the following jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".box").submit(function(e) {       
      e.preventDefault();
        var input_value = $(".textbox").val();
        $("<li>"+ input_value +" <br /> <form class='box'><input type='text' name='textbox' class='textbox reply'></form> <ul class='list'></ul></div></li>")
        .prependTo($(this).siblings('.list').first());
    });
});
```

Everything works fine when I prependTo() to the existing HTML but once I try to prependTo() to the element that was created by javascript I run into an error.

I created the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hV2Rr/) to illustrate

Comment: it can not find the prepended <ul> to prependTo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **event delegation**. Therefore change

```
$(".box").submit(function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on("submit", ".box", function (e) {
```

*To be able to utilize [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) use jQuery 1.7 or higher*

To correctly get values from newly inserted fields also change

```
var input_value = $(".textbox").val();
```

to

```
var input_value = $(this).find(".textbox").val();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTyWC/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using jQuery 1.6.4 use event delegation using [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). If you are using jQuery >= 1.7 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".box").live('submit', function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        var input_value = $(".textbox").val();
        $("<li>"+ input_value +" <br /> <form class='box'><input type='text' name='textbox' class='textbox reply'></form> <ul class='list'></ul></div></li>")
        .prependTo($(this).siblings('.list').first());
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N8spf/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the newly created element is yet not pushed into the DOM. You need to first push the elements in DOM (by this I mean do something like .html() so the element is now present in the DOM) and after doing this you can use `prependTo()` to the newly created element